# Can we control the print dialog box in chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i am looking for how to control the print dialog or print preview in google chrome by javascript. i don't want it to show the dialog. just when you click print and it directly print page without any dialog. if any one know please tell me.

Comment: you can try using html2pdf  https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are in control of the browser, you can start chrome in kiosk mode. I've found [this](https://www.netohq.com/support/s/article/disable-print-preview-of-receipts-in-chrome) article that shows the steps.

Comment: yes i try using "--kiosk" mode, but it still show the dialog.

Comment: and i try using "--kiosk-printing" and it show the dialog for a while. but what i want is do not show any thing, just print only